# Windows 8.1 AppBar Ellipsis

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml, windows-8.1

In Windows 8.1 RTM apps like Calendar come with an AppBar with ellipsis.

I'm trying to replicate that but can't find any details on such functionality being added to the AppBar control in Windows 8.1.

A friend has suggested to make a `Grid` with three `Circle`s in a `StackPanel` to be placed at the bottom of the page which opens the AppBar when clicked.

Is there a better way to accomplish the AppBar style in Windows 8.1's calendar app?

Bonus Question: The Calendar app and if I recall correctly the News app have an amazing navigation AppBar which pulls down from the top. How do I create that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was answered on your x-post in MSDN forums.

The ellipsis is a custom thing in those apps and not a general property of AppBar currently.  Additionally the navigation element in the Bing apps is the WinJS NavBar control...not presently implemented as a XAML control.

Comment: Thanks much. Hopefully NavBar will come to XAML soon :/

Comment: It doesn't look difficult to achieve at all - it isn't attached to the app bar, it's essentially a button which opens the app bar.

Comment: In fact the ellipsis is available as a glyph in the Segoe UI Symbol font - `&#xEC02;`

Answer (score 0):

Jeremy Alles has provided an example of how this can be simulated with a button in a border:

http://www.japf.fr/2013/10/winrt-introducing-the-appbarhint-control/

The one change I've had to make to get it working properly is where you reference the control on your page. Instead of:

`<controls:AppBarHint Grid.Row="1" />`

you need to use

`<controls:AppBarHint Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />`

For an extra bit of tidyness, change the main grid so that there is a third row:

```
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="140"/>
    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    <RowDefinition Height="15"/>
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

and change the row reference to `Grid.Row="2"`. The reason for doing this is that it ensures that the app bar hint isn't obscuring anything else in row 1, e.g. a horizontal scroll bar.

Finally, the Mail app provides a tooltip and you can add that in the control's XAML:

`ToolTipService.ToolTip="Show more commands (Windows logo key+Z, or right-click)"`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the ellipsis is built into the WinJS AppBar control. Once you get the latest WinJS bits from GitHub (https://github.com/winjs/winjs/), you can use the new AppBar closedDisplayMode property to get the ellipsis:

```
<div data-win-control="WinJS.UI.AppBar" data-win options="{closedDisplayMode:'minimal'}">
     <button data-win-control="WinJS.UI.AppBarCommand" data-win-options="{id:'cmdAdd',label:'Add',icon:'add'}"></button>
     <button data-win-control="WinJS.UI.AppBarCommand" data-win-options="{id:'cmdRemove',label:'Remove',icon:'remove'}"></button>
</div>
```

You can find the demo here: http://try.buildwinjs.com/#appbar